# Change Layout for Page SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I created a page in SharePoint 2013 with Business Intelligence Center Template. I had then uploaded a template and published it. After editing same page, I do not see the option "Page Layout" in the ribbon. Kindly help with the issue.

Comment: Are you able to see other layouts?

Comment: yes am administrator for this site

Comment: And uploaded template is?

Comment: Yes I uploaded master page and page layout also I uploaded css, jquery and javascripts folder

Comment: You can validate if files are published in major version.